# Drools with eval function rule won't fire

Tags: eval, drools, rule-engine

I have the following rule:

```
rule "AddSource"
when
    $model : MFMModel ()
    Node( type == "source", funName : name )
    $ffs : Structure( ffsName : name )
    WholePart( structure == ffsName, ffunction == funName )
    eval (Test.checkExsit($model,$ffs))


then
    System.out.println( ffsName + ":" + funName);
    Source s = new Source( funName );
    insert (s);
    $ffs.addToStructure( s );
    System.out.println(Test.checkExsit($model,$ffs));
end
```

The rule fires when I delete the eval function in the when part, and the printout says Test.checkExsit($model,$ffs) return true.

But with the eval function, the rule will never fire.

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Might be good if you post your code for `Test.checkExsit()` as well.  Also move the last System.out.println() up to the top of your `then`-part to make sure it really is `true` in the `when`: It might be that the `$ffs.addToStructure(s)` affects the result of `Test.checkExsit`, so that it is still `false` when evaluated in the `when` part.

Comment: I moved the printout to top and it still print true.

Comment: @Miichi Oh, you are right about the changes, actually it is false before the when, because another rule change this variable.